# If an IGBT's collector-emitter max voltage is 600 V, Do I need 1 kV rated capacitors on the output side?

Tags: power, capacitor, solar-cell, igbt, replacement

I'm fixing this solar PV diverter (pictures attached at the bottom of this post), other than the traces it has a blown IGBT and 2 capacitors.

The datasheet for the IGBT (model FGH40T65SPD) is here:

https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/fgh40t65spd-d.pdf

I've tested the other non blown capacitors and found the missing ones are 12 uF and 56 nF, the max output from the IGBT collector-emitter voltage can reach 600 V though so do I need to use caps rated at 1 kV? On the datasheet it looks like normal operation is around 20 V but I'm not 100%. What are your thoughts?

[image]

[image]

Thanks

Some pictures here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNbzE.jpg

Comment: C5 looks connected to emitter, in parallel with 100 kohm. But was there a big resistor in series coming from the emitter, burned away along with its pads? Make and model of the inverter?

Comment: Yeah C5 and C2 are both connected to the emitters trace. They're the only caps that are missing, there's a picture on the imgur link I added that shows the same curcuit undamaged. There's 4 of them on this board. It's a immersun solar pv

Comment: Holy moly that's a bad design! Note to self: never buy anything from immersun.

Comment: Haha yeah these things mess up alot I've heard, it's used to switch solar power from the batteries once fully charged to the immersion heater. £500 for a new unit too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The picture shows the driving circuit. The voltage there must be limited to Vge, which is +-20V for your IGBT.
Standard 50V X7R is probably sufficient.

*There also isn't enough clearance under C5 to allow such voltages, and the parts don't exist.*

---

Note: the picture also shows delamination of the pcb and possible internal layer damage. See the stain going up to C47 and R51.

Comment: Brilliant, I'll get the 250v just to be safe

Comment: Brilliant, I've posted a couple of other places and people have pretty much said I was stupid for thinking I can use under 1kv. It didn't make sense to me and they're either stupidly expensive or I can't find the part. Thank you for your input, it's a great help. The delamination was done by me when using my heat gun to remove the IGBT, it lifted a little but nothing too major as I stopped straight away.

Comment: @Jeroen3 Both capacitors are connected to emitter so 1 kV rating it is.

Comment: @winny what is the other side connected to?

Comment: Would the trace width be anything to go off? It is pretty thin going into these 2 capacitors. Here's a couple of pictures, the emitter voltage would come in at the opposite side of the arrows where R16 is written. https://imgur.com/a/ryXW1vx

Comment: Looks like bootstrapping for the gate driver.

Comment: You don't give much to go on dude! Anyway, the max voltage for the 10uf smd multilayer capacitors seems to be 100, so it can't possibly need a 1kv

I need 2 different caps, on my testers they're coming up as 50nf and 11.x uf, so I'm guessing they will be 47nf and 10uf as those other values aren't available and it's within 10%
I can find 1kv 47nf's but the max 10uf's I can get is 100v

Comment: Did you unsolder and measure them from an adjacent driver? Is D2 a Zener diode? If you measure 12 uF, that must be in circuit with lots of other capacitors connected.

Comment: @CptChronic Yeah, 47nF and 10uF looks right. If you derive a schematic you can probably guess the values that way as well.

Comment: Yes they were unsoldered before testing them, I used two different test meters too. @jeroen3 see how it goes, I've ordered them now, they'll be here tomorrow. Hopefully the thing doesn't go bang again 